# Drag and Drop items in Windows application and Get the StandardDataFormats of the items

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop

I am developing an windows application where I drag and dropped an items(File, Folder, URL, Text and etc.) then I want to check the dropped item **StandardDataFormats** [StorageItems or WebLink or Text].

Here is my implementation idea :

```
void DroppedItems(object sender, DragEventArgs items) 
{
    if (items.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if (items.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
    {
        //Do something
    }
    if (items.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This implementation works fine for File, File+Folder and Text but when I dropped any web-link all the if statement is executed.
How can I check the **StandardDataFormats** so that when I dropped web link only my second if statement is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Drag and Drop items in Windows application and Get the StandardDataFormats of the items

The problem is that the dropped item is WebLink as well as internet shortcut. so it will execute the second statement. for this scenario, we suggest you use if-else statement, and place WebLink in the first statement, if it is true, it will skip the following statement.

```
if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
{

    //Do something
}
else if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
{
    //Do something
}
else if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
{
    // Do something

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find it out that DataView contains multiple format. I want to know that that's the only way to check or is there any way to check individually ??

Comment: Yep, Currently, there is no other way to check individually. I think you could use `DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync()` to get items first, and then check them with file type, because weblink's file type is `.url`.

Comment: It will helpful for others to know that dropped item contains multiple dataformat type